# Nativescript-angular after http service call, view is not updated (Angular 5)

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

**Nativescript-angular after http service call, view is not updated (Angular 5 ).**

Find the below code where I have written the http service call then the response is assigned to view which is not updating in view page. If I do any other event like mouse over text box, the view is getting updated.
  **componet.ts file**

```
this.orderService.getProductBySKU('DR1056.01534XXL')
    .subscribe(resProduct => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.processing = false;                
         });
    }
```

**Service file**

```
getProductBySKU(sku) {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('currentUserToken');
    return this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + 'get-product-by-sku?sku=' + sku, this.config.basicAuth())
 .map(response => response);
```

}

**Note : By default this.processing is given as True in constructor which displays in view, after service call this.processing is assigned as False, but which displays only True. If I click any text box or button click, this.processing is changed to False in view.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off I'd recomend using the HttpClient params option to avoid potential URL escaping problems:

```
this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + 'get-product-by-sku', {...this.config.basicAuth(), params: { sku: sku }})
```

```

As for the processing, try forcing a change detection:

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
(...)
this.orderService.getProductBySKU('DR1056.01534XXL')
    .subscribe(resProduct => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.processing = false;                
            this.ref.detectChanges();
         });
    }
```

If that doesn't work, please provide a snippet of your template.

Comment: It does work. But why we should force to update the view. In earlier, I didn't do force even it works.

Comment: Yeah, it should work. I really can't tell why it isn't. I had to use ngZone a lot of times in Nativescript, but I'm not sure why it isn't working for you.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue? Anybody know specific reason why it's not working without firing change detection?